# HttpResponseException Error on reads events

Tags: events, titanium, google-calendar-api

I am developing an application for `titanium android/ios` in which I need to read the events from Google Calendar.

I started with OAuth 2.0 for titanium and got the access Token, I can read no of calendar and events too, but I found `HttpResponseException` error app is going crash and give us some error are shown below.

```
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: (TiHttpClient-9) [495,189738] HTTP Error (org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException): Not Found
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:275)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:219)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1334)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: Could you please provide the code that produces the error?

Comment: xhr.onerror = function() {
alert("2")
  Ti.API.info('Response xhr ' + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
  alert('Error , Something went wrong please try again.');
  // alert(" below Response New: " + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
 };
 xhr.open('GET', url);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + googleAuth.getAccessToken());
 xhr.send();

}

Comment: You should edit the post and put the code there. But don't just paste it but format it as code.

Comment: Welcome to stack:    Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Character limit in the comment  filed  is very low ,so i am not able to post my code .please provide me your email id .